# Lazyloading in webgalileo faces table component

Tags: jsf, lazy-loading

I am trying to implement a lazy loading for the webgalileo faces table component. I know this is an outdated technology, but I have to work with it since the code was written a long time back and need to tweak it a bit to implement new features into that. Can anyone give a headstart on how to do  this since the support is also not available for the webgalieo components?

Comment: Why this was voted down since there is no documentation or help available online and I am looking for some help in this regard from people who may have used webgalileo faces before.

Comment: Perhaps because of the lack of information to start working with. This generic approach may be helpful to get started: http://wiki.apache.org/myfaces/WorkingWithLargeTables